# Split table into a new slide powerpoint Open XML

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, openxml-sdk

I try to export  data from my database to powerpoint through Open XML I create a table inside the first slide but the problem is when I have a lot of data. How I can create a new slide when the first slide is full of data?
I didn't find any indication how I can get the height of my table to generate the new slide
Any idea? Please...

```
   Private Shared Function GenerateTable() As A.Table
        Dim tableSources As String(,) = New String(,) {{"name", "age", "gg", "hhha"}, {"Tom", "25", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "aaa"}, {"Tom", "25", "aaa", "aaa"}, {"Tom", "25", "aaa", ""}, {"Tom", "25", "", ""}, {"Tom", "25", "aaa", "aaa"}, {"Tom", "25", "ee", "www"}}


        Dim table As New A.Table()


        Dim tableProperties As New A.TableProperties() With { _
          .FirstRow = True, _
          .BandRow = True _
        }

        Dim tableStyleId As New A.TableStyleId()
        tableStyleId.Text = "{5C22544A-7EE6-4342-B048-85BDC9FD1C3A}"

        tableProperties.Append(tableStyleId)


        Dim tableGrid1 As New A.TableGrid()
        Dim gridColumn1 As New A.GridColumn() With { _
         .Width = 2048000L _
        }
        Dim gridColumn2 As New A.GridColumn() With { _
         .Width = 2048000L _
        }
        Dim gridColumn3 As New A.GridColumn() With { _
       .Width = 2048000L _
      }
        Dim gridColumn4 As New A.GridColumn() With { _
         .Width = 2048000L _
        }



        tableGrid1.Append(gridColumn1)
        tableGrid1.Append(gridColumn2)
        tableGrid1.Append(gridColumn3)
        tableGrid1.Append(gridColumn4)
        table.Append(tableProperties)
        table.Append(tableGrid1)
        For row As Integer = 0 To tableSources.GetLength(0) - 1
            Dim tableRow As New A.TableRow() With { _
              .Height = 570840L _
            }
            For column As Integer = 0 To 3
                tableRow.Append(CreateTextCell(tableSources.GetValue(row, column).ToString()))
            Next

            table.Append(tableRow)
        Next

        Return table
    End Function
```

Comment: @hamza437-were you able to solve this problem, even i have a similar situation. in case if you have solved, could you please share the solution

Comment: there is no solution i fix the number of row in  every slide before inserting the table ,sorry

Comment: @hamza437- yes, even i ended up having only one table in slide and limiting the number of rows to some number, which fits into the slide.Thank you :)